# How do you create encryption keys for 'n' clients via one server?

Tags: java, encryption, server, serversocket

I am currently doing research for a project for my practicum class. I am seeking to create a Java application front-end that will interact via a Java back-end. Encryption itself isn't too difficult, as I have dabbled in it before. The difference here is that I need my back-end to generate its own encryption keys and the clients to generate their own. After those keys are generated, I need to share those keys. Is there a Java library to aid in this exchange of keys? When I did encryption in the past, I was able to read in the encryption keys from a text file, so I never even generated keys. I understand concepts like asymmetric/symmetric encryption, but I am still lost.

Comment: See [`javax.crypto.KeyAgreement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyAgreement.html).

Comment: That was helpful! Thanks!